# How does applying a 1-by-1 convolution (bottleneck layer) between conv. layers change the output?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network

A 1-by-1 convolutional layer can (e.g.) be used to reduce the number of operations between two conv. layers.

**Example:** applying a $5 \times 5 \times 32$ conv. with same padding onto a $28 \times 28 \times 192$ feature volume yields $D_{output} * D_{filter} = 28 * 28 * 32 * 5 * 5 * 192 \approx 120 * 10^6$ operations. (image 2)

Putting a 1-by-1 conv. in between with, e.g. 16 channels reduces this operation to $12.4 * 10^6$ operations: $ops_{conv. \to 1 \times 1} + ops_{1 \times 1 \to 5 \times 5} = 28 * 28 * 16 * 192 + 28 * 28 * 32 * 5 * 5 * 16 \approx 12.4 * 10^6$ operations. (image 2)

This setup is illustrated through drawings of Andrew Ng below.

**My question is:** is there a formal derivation/proof how this **changes/affects** the computed output values (activations) compared to applying the $5 \times 5$ conv. directly?

[image: drawing by Andrew Ng; excl. 1-by-1]
[image: drawing by Andrew Ng; incl. 1-by-1]

Answer (score 0):

No matter what convolution filter size it is, the channel size is equal to the number of its convolution filters. You know single filter makes single channel of an image. In the case of 1x1, you don't need to pad input representation because the filter fits with each pixel.

Comment: thanks, but this is not quite what I'm asking for. I'm looking for a formula or some kind of expression how inserting a 1x1 conv. changes the computed output values compared to the initial pipeline. Also, the 1x1 is not padded, the 5x5 is.

Answer (score 0):

You could formulate the operation of a convolutional layer (without padding and implemented as cross-correlation) as follows:
$$y_{iab} = \sum_j \sum_{k_1} \sum_{k_2} w_{ijk_1k_2} x_{j(a+k_1)(b+k_2)}$$

Applying two convolutions sequentially simply requires plugging in another convolution at the position of $x$.
However, since this first convolution is a 1x1 convolution, the $k_i$ sums disappear and we obtain
$$\begin{aligned}
  y_{iab} &= \sum_j \sum_{k_1} \sum_{k_2} w^{(2)}_{ijk_1k_2} \Big(\sum_l w^{(1)}_{jl} x_{l(a+k_1)(b+k_2)}\Big) \\
  &= \sum_l \sum_{k_1} \sum_{k_2} \underbrace{\Big(\sum_j w^{(2)}_{ijk_1k_2} w^{(1)}_{jl}\Big)}_{w_{ilk_1k_2}'} x_{l(a+k_1)(b+k_2)}.
\end{aligned}$$

As a result, this particular convolution is equivalent to a single convolution with the weights computed as above.
Note that this result is only valid if there are **no non-linearities**. As soon as you have some non-linearities after the convolutions, the two different ways of doing the convolution are no longer equivalent!